# Deleting contacts in the phonebook on java

Tags: java, user-interface, phonebook

Please Help! unable to add the delete Contact method in the phonebook on java. Such that when enter the name of the person, the contact in text file will delete. There is no error in the code but the delete method is not working. The text file also there which contain the names and numbers of the person.The code is given below. Please help me to add this method.

Here is Phone_book.java class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class Entry {
public String name, number, notes;
}
public class Phone_Book {
    public static Entry[] contactList = new Entry[200];
    public static int num_entries;
    public static Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static Object entryList;
    public static void readPhone_Book(String Phonebook) throws Exception {
    File phonebook;
    phonebook = new File(Phonebook);
    Scanner S = new Scanner(phonebook);
    while (S.hasNext()) {
        contactList[num_entries] = new Entry();
        contactList[num_entries].name = S.nextLine();
        contactList[num_entries].number = S.nextLine();
        contactList[num_entries].notes = S.nextLine();
        num_entries++;
    }
    S.close();
}
public static void addContact() {
    String name = GUIphonebook.txtName.getText();
    String number = GUIphonebook.txtNumber.getText();
    String notes = GUIphonebook.txtNotes.getText();
    contactList[num_entries] = new Entry();
    contactList[num_entries].name = name;
    contactList[num_entries].number = number;
    contactList[num_entries].notes = notes;
    num_entries++;
}

public static void deleteContact()
{
   
        for (int i = 0; i < num_entries; i++)
        {
            contactList[i] = contactList[i+1];         
        }

        num_entries--;

    }

public static int find(String Name) {
    for (int i = 0; i < num_entries; i++) {
        if (contactList[i].name.equalsIgnoreCase(Name))
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
public static void displayContact() {
    String name = GUIphonebook.txtName.getText();
    int x = find(name);
    String name1 = contactList[x].name;
    String number = contactList[x].number;
    String notes = contactList[x].notes;
    GUIphonebook.txtName.setText(name1);
    GUIphonebook.txtNumber.setText(number);
    GUIphonebook.txtNotes.setText(notes);
}
public static void listAllContacts() {
    String all = "";
    int i = 0;
    while (i < num_entries) {
        all = all
                + (contactList[i].name + "\n" + contactList[i].number
                + "\n" + contactList[i].notes + "\n" + "\n");
        i++;
    }
    GUIphonebook.txtAll.setText(all);
}
public static void sortList() {
    int i;
    Entry temp;
    temp = new Entry();
    for (int j = 0; j < num_entries; j++) {
        for (i = j + 1; i < num_entries; i++) {
            if (contactList[j].name.compareToIgnoreCase(contactList[i].name) > 0) {
                temp = contactList[j];
                contactList[j] = contactList[i];
                contactList[i] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
public static void CopyPhoneBookToFile(String FileName) throws Exception {
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(FileName);
    PrintStream P = new PrintStream(out);
    for (int i = 0; i < num_entries; i++) {
        P.println(contactList[i].name);
        P.println(contactList[i].number);
        P.println(contactList[i].notes);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: what do you mean unable to add method. are you saying you are not able to implement method. I can't see delete method implementation.

Comment: I tried to implement it but it doesn't work

Comment: You can [edit] your question to show us what you tried - and clarify exactly what you mean by "it doesn't work": (1) Describe what happens, and (2) what you want to happen instead. Also show us (3) the text (suitably formatted) of any error messages you may be getting. You may also want to (4) _remove_ any code from the question which is not directly relevant to the problem. In other words, try to provide a [mre]. (You may even find that you solve your own problem, while creating the MRE.)

Comment: I have updated it. Kindly look and help